# I want to open intent handler and get result intent data in nativescript vue

Tags: android, android-intent, nativescript-vue

i want to create a upi://pay deeplinking for my android application
problem is i have android core code as sample to implement but when i try to use in nativescript vue android i get null intent

i have using openurl utils to open intent in nativescript

var utilityModule = require("utils/utils");
utilityModule.openUrl("upi://pay?pa=xxxxxxxxx@upi&am=1.0&tn=txnid221011"                 );

```
     @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("upi://pay?pa="+payeeAddress+"&pn="+payeeName+"&tn="+transactionNote+
                    "&am="+amount+"&cu="+currencyUnit);
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: uri: "+uri);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivityForResult(intent,1);
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: requestCode: "+requestCode);
    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: resultCode: "+resultCode);
    //txnId=UPI20b6226edaef4c139ed7cc38710095a3&responseCode=00&ApprovalRefNo=null&Status=SUCCESS&txnRef=undefined
    //txnId=UPI608f070ee644467aa78d1ccf5c9ce39b&responseCode=ZM&ApprovalRefNo=null&Status=FAILURE&txnRef=undefined

    if(data!=null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: data: " + data.getStringExtra("response"));
        String res = data.getStringExtra("response");
        String search = "SUCCESS";
        if (res.toLowerCase().contains(search.toLowerCase())) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Payment Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Payment Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [nativescript-urlhandler](https://github.com/hypery2k/nativescript-urlhandler) plugin. I only tested the demo, but it worked.